# Getting root folder name with PS

Tags: windows, powershell, task, scheduled-tasks

I am trying to create a PowerShell script to fetch the root folder's name where in their subdirectories files with error names are present with today's date. Below is the sample code I have tried so far to pick the folder names.

Root Log folder - C:\Errorlogs, contains many other application log level folders.

```
$targetDir="C:\Errorlogs"
Get-ChildItem $targetDir -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Force -Filter "*Error*"| 
where {([datetime]::now.Date -eq $_.lastwritetime.Date)} |
select FullName
```

I have tried the above code; however, it's giving me the whole path as result, whereas I only need the folder name.

Result - C:\Errorlogs\AsyncCreateUsersAPIProcessor\202302\04\Error.txt

Required - AsyncCreateUsersAPIProcessor

Answer (score 0):

Use string LastIndexOf and SubString

```
$rootPath = "C:\Temp\Errorlogs"
$date = [DateTime]::Now.ToString("yyyyMM\\\\dd")

$pattern = '\\(?<folder>\w+)\\' + $date +  '\\Error.*$'
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $rootPath -Recurse | Select-Object -Property Fullname | Where-Object {$_.Fullname -Match $pattern}
foreach($file in $files)
{
   $file.Fullname -match $pattern
   Write-Host "folder = " $Matches.folder
}
```

Comment: Root Log folder - "C:\Errorlogs"     Inside the root folder are many application-level folders. I need to search the file with "error" in the filename and with PowerShell show just the application-level folder for example - AsyncCreateUsersAPIProcessor.

Comment: Thanks for the big help, @jdweng Instead of pulling the folder ($date = [DateTime]::Now.ToString("yyyyMM\\dd")
), can we fetch the file created in last 5 or 10 minutes irrespective of the date folder?

Comment: I updated to use Regex.  Do you also need by date?

Comment: Simply curious, if today's files are in an older date folder, then it's not showing the folder name in the result, only if the files are in today's date folder.

Comment: You can modify Where-Object like this : Get-ChildItem | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)}  Use -and to get by name and date.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can do it just with splitting the path using `\` as delimiter then picking the 3rd token (2nd index of an array):

```
$targetDir = "C:\Errorlogs"

Get-ChildItem $targetDir -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Force -Filter "*Error*" |
    Where-Object { [datetime]::Now.Date -eq $_.LastWriteTime.Date } |
    Select-Object @{ N='Name'; E={ $_.FullName.Split('\')[2] }}
```

Another option if you want 2 levels up in the folder hierarchy is to query the `.Directory` property of the file then the `.Parent` property of the parent folder (2 times or as many times as needed):

```
$targetDir = "C:\Errorlogs"

Get-ChildItem $targetDir -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Force -Filter "*Error*" |
    Where-Object { [datetime]::Now.Date -eq $_.LastWriteTime.Date } |
    Select-Object @{ N='Name'; E={ $_.Directory.Parent.Parent.Name }}
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as the subfolders inside the folder you are after all have numeric-only names, you can loop backwards to get at the first non-numeric foldername and output that.

```
$targetDir = "C:\Errorlogs"

Get-ChildItem -Path $targetDir -File -Filter "*Error*" -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
Where-Object { [datetime]::Now.Date -eq $_.LastWriteTime.Date } | ForEach-Object {
    $parentDir = $_.Directory
    while ($parentDir.Name -match '^\d+$') { $parentDir = $parentDir.Parent }
    $parentDir.Name
}
```

That way, even a path `C:\Errorlogs\AsyncCreateUsersAPIProcessor\202302\02\04\1234\567\Error.txt` would produce folder name `AsyncCreateUsersAPIProcessor`